# Error committing Trunk after merging Branch back in. How to resolve?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, merge, commit, ankhsvn

I'm getting the following subversion error:

```
Subversion does not allow to commit this combination of files and directories at once. 
Directory deletes must be recursive and this would commit other files:

Deleted directory: 
    D:\mm32.net\Trunk\MyApp.Web\App_Themes\Factsheet_print\Images\Risk

Directory to commit: 
    D:\mm32.net\Trunk 
Not to commit: 
    D:\mm32.net\Trunk\MyApp.Web\App_Themes\Factsheet_offline\Images\Risk\Very-High-Risk.jpg
```

I had a branch where I deleted loads of stuff that was redundant. I then merged trunk into that branch. Everything was fine, so I committed. Then I merged that Branch into Trunk. When I’m trying to commit Trunk now it’s giving me the error.

Can somebody point out how to resolve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with Tortoise SVN and it worked...